# Is there a USB driver for the alacatel onetouch 983?

Tags: usb, adb

I have purchased an alcatel one touch 983 running android 2.3.7 for development purposes. So it is critical that I can view logcat messages and connect to it from eclipse via USB. But so far I have failed to get the connection to work. I have installed something called "Qualcomm USB Host Driver version 2.0.6.7 for Windows 2000/XP/Server 2003/Vista/Win7" which I though was the right solution - but when I right click on "onetouch" in device manager and then tell the update wizard that my driver is in "E:\Alcatel USB driver\usb_host_driver_2.0.6.8\Win32\WinXP", it reports "The hardware was not installed because the wizard cannot find the necessary software".

Comment: Have you checked with the [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/)?

Comment: Wow, that worked. I have no idea what the universal adb driver is, but it worked. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Glad to read! I've made it an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you cannot find a device-specific driver, it's worth trying the [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/). It should work with most devices, so I'd even say this is the first one to try -- especially when having multiple devices, as this gets you rid of the need for multiple drivers.